# PLS-00382 when using a UDT in PL/SQL function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am trying to create a package on Oracle. This package holds two functions (i do need to create two function, I cannot unite them) but I have got this error on lines:

```
mD(1) := rel_mahalanobis_distance_aux_3( A1,
B1,B2,B3);
x_minus_y(2) := ABS(A2 - B2);
mD(2) := rel_mahalanobis_distance_aux_3( A2,
B1,B2,B3);
x_minus_y(3) := ABS(A3 - B3);
mD(3) := rel_mahalanobis_distance_aux_3( A3,
B1,B2,B3);
```

The error:

> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Errors on lines:

```
mD(1) := rel_mahalanobis_distance_aux_3( A1,
B1,B2,B3);
x_minus_y(2) := ABS(A2 - B2);
mD(2) := rel_mahalanobis_distance_aux_3( A2,
B1,B2,B3);
x_minus_y(3) := ABS(A3 - B3);
mD(3) := rel_mahalanobis_distance_aux_3( A3,
B1,B2,B3);
```

The package code

```
CREATE PACKAGE mahalanobis_distance_package AS
max_d NUMBER;
TYPE tbNumber IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
function rel_mahalanobis_distance_aux_3( A NUMBER,B1 NUMBER,B2 NUMBER,B3 NUMBER)
RETURN  tbNumber;function rel_mahalanobis_distance_3(
A1 NUMBER, A2 NUMBER, A3 NUMBER,
B1 NUMBER,B2 NUMBER,B3 NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER ;
END mahalanobis_distance_package;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY mahalanobis_distance_package AS
function rel_mahalanobis_distance_aux_3( A NUMBER,
B1 NUMBER,B2 NUMBER,B3 NUMBER) RETURN  tbNumber IS
tbNumber_obj tbNumber;
BEGIN
max_d := 0;
FOR j IN 1..3 LOOP
tbNumber_obj(j) := 0;
END LOOP;
tbNumber_obj(1) := ABS(A - B1);
IF tbNumber_obj(1) > max_d THEN
max_d := tbNumber_obj(1);
END IF;
tbNumber_obj(2) := ABS(A - B2);
IF tbNumber_obj(2) > max_d THEN
max_d := tbNumber_obj(2);
END IF;
tbNumber_obj(3) := ABS(A - B3);
IF tbNumber_obj(3) > max_d THEN
max_d := tbNumber_obj(3);
END IF;
return tbNumber_obj;
END rel_mahalanobis_distance_aux_3;
function rel_mahalanobis_distance_3(
A1 NUMBER, A2 NUMBER, A3 NUMBER,
B1 NUMBER,B2 NUMBER,B3 NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
total NUMBER := 0;
aux NUMBER;
TYPE tbNumber IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
TYPE tbNumberMatrix IS TABLE OF tbNumber INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
mA tbNumberMatrix;
mD tbNumberMatrix;
x_minus_y INTEGER_ARRAY := INTEGER_ARRAY();
BEGIN
x_minus_y.extend(3) ;
FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
FOR j IN 1..3 LOOP
mA(i)(j) := 0;
mD(i)(j) := 0;
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
x_minus_y(1) := ABS(A1 - B1);


mD(1) := rel_mahalanobis_distance_aux_3( A1,
B1,B2,B3);
x_minus_y(2) := ABS(A2 - B2);
mD(2) := rel_mahalanobis_distance_aux_3( A2,
B1,B2,B3);
x_minus_y(3) := ABS(A3 - B3);
mD(3) := rel_mahalanobis_distance_aux_3( A3,
B1,B2,B3);
FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
FOR j IN 1..3 LOOP
mA(i)(j) := 1 - (mD(i)(j)/max_d);
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
aux := 0;
FOR j IN 1..3 LOOP
aux := aux + x_minus_y(j) * mA(j)(i);
END LOOP;
total := total + x_minus_y(i)*aux;
END LOOP;
RETURN  POWER(total,0.5);
END rel_mahalanobis_distance_3;
END mahalanobis_distance_package;
/
```

The datatype seems to be right. 
What can I do to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line inside function `rel_mahalanobis_distance_3`

```
TYPE tbNumber IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

You have already declared `tbNumber`  in package sepcification ( global scope ) and you are re-declaring it, which makes it incompatible while doing the assignment

Remove that line, your error message should disappear.

Also, I don't see the declaration for type `INTEGER_ARRAY` in your code, hope you are using  an available `TYPE` or declaring it somewhere.